# Unzipping with python's ZipFile lib give a strange result

Tags: python, unzip

Given a zip file and the python ZipFile library I'm expriencing a strange output when extracting : the files which are located at the root of the archive get extracted to a sub-directory named with the archive name itself.

Here is the way i use the ZipFile library :

```
#!/usr/bin/X11/python

import sys
import urllib
import zipfile
import os.path
import os
import tempfile

def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            # Path traversal defense copied from
            # http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/http/server.py#l789
            words = member.filename.split('/')
            path = dest_dir
            for word in words[:-1]:
                drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
                head, word = os.path.split(word)
                if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir, ''): continue
                path = os.path.join(path, word)
            zf.extract(member, path)

try:
    # Get the latest release
    print 'Downloading stack archive...'
    (vagrantstack, infoheaders) = urllib.urlretrieve ('https://github.com/jquery/globalize/archive/master.zip')

    # Unzip in the project folder
    print 'Unzipping...'
    unzip(vagrantstack, '.')

finally:
    urllib.urlcleanup()
```

This should reproduce the exact structure of the jquery/globalize repository, but instead all the root files go in a sub directory...

Someone can point out the probleme here?

Disclaimer : the unzip function itself is not mine but seems correct to me.

Edit : Here is the output i get :

```
➜  test-py  ./test.py
Downloading stack archive...
Unzipping...
➜  test-py  ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 6 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 globalize-master
-rwxr-xr-x 1 adrien adrien 1032 juil. 21 12:23 test.py
➜  test-py  ls -l globalize-master
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 5 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 doc
drwxr-xr-x 2 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 globalize-master
drwxr-xr-x 8 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 src
drwxr-xr-x 6 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 test
➜  test-py  ls -l globalize-master/globalize-master
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien   354 juil. 21 12:23 bower.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien  1052 juil. 21 12:23 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien  6809 juil. 21 12:23 Gruntfile.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien  1826 juil. 21 12:23 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien  2397 juil. 21 12:23 package.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 adrien adrien 14151 juil. 21 12:23 README.md
➜  test-py
```

The globalize-master/globalize-master folder shouldn't exists and its content should be at the root.

Comment: What does the listen of files in the zip file show?

Comment: What do you mean by the "listen"? You can see what is should output by getting to this repository (it's just for the example) : https://github.com/jquery/globalize

Comment: And what directory to the root files go into? and what do the others go into? (The information should be in the question and not on an offsite resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The archive you are trying to download *does not have top level files*.
The archive consists of a single directory called `globalize-master` that contains all the files, so the behaviour you see is correct.

If you extract the contents using `unzip` you'll see the same behaviour:

```
$ls
globalize-master.zip
$unzip globalize-master.zip 
Archive:  globalize-master.zip
300a9dc6cb4a08eb847c8565ee01eae4cd9aa35c
   creating: globalize-master/
 extracting: globalize-master/.bowerrc  
  [...]
  inflating: globalize-master/test/util.js  
$ls -l
totale 116
drwxrwxr-x 5 username username   4096 lug 13 07:35 globalize-master
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 113313 lug 21 12:44 globalize-master.zip
```

---

Reading the sources it's pretty clear that all the stuff that the `unzip` function is doing with the filename is useless, because it's already being taken care of by `ZipFile.extract`.
The correct version of `unzip` is:

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        for member in zf.infolist():
            zf.extract(member, dest_dir)
```

which produces the expected output.

Note that this is pretty much equivalent to using the [`extractall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) method:

```
def unzip(source_filename, dest_dir):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source_filename) as zf:
        zf.extractall(dest_dir)
```

Comment: It's not excalty what I'm getting :
`➜  test-py  ./test.py
Downloading stack archive...

Unzipping...
➜  test-py  ls -l 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 6 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 globalize-master
-rwxr-xr-x 1 adrien adrien 1032 juil. 21 12:23 test.py
➜  test-py  ls -l globalize-master 
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 5 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 doc
drwxr-xr-x 2 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 globalize-master
drwxr-xr-x 8 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 src
drwxr-xr-x 6 adrien adrien 4096 juil. 21 12:23 test`

Comment: The output is not displayed well in comments... try executing the script i give in my first post, and you'll see there is a folder globalize-master/globalize-master that contains all the root files.
Here is a paste of what I get : http://pastebin.com/tCM5pXpH

Comment: @AdrienLUCAS Do you actually need to specify the location where the archive should be extracted? Changing `zf.extract(member, path)` to `zf.extract(member)` resolves the issue. You can then move the directory using `shutil` as a workaround...

Comment: I though the second argument of the extract function prevented from some directory traversal issues. But according to the documentation, the probleme is sloved in 2.6.

I still don't understand why it doesn't work with the second argument, but your correction solved the issue, thanks!

Comment: @AdrienLUCAS I'm investigating a bit the sources right now. For one thing, all the stuff that you are doing with `splitdrive` etc seems useless because it's already done by `zipfile`. Maybe the fact that the code does that things twice is producing some bogus path in that particular circumstance. I just tried removing all that code and it suddenly works.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a problem somewhere in `unzip()`. It's creating a `globalize-master` sub-directory in all directories, not just the root.

If you trust the zip file source you could just use `zf.extractall(dest_dir)`. [`extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) should be safe for Python 2.7.4 and later.